# Query varchar date with between

Tags: mysql

How can i select a date stored as varchar (format: "2012.04") with the BETWEEN operator?

I need to select a one year interval on this field.

Now i'm trying with this, but this gives my MySQL syntax error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT monthcol
FROM bo_alerts
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(monthcol , '%Y.%m') BETWEEN
           (STR_TO_DATE('2012.04', '%Y.%m') AND STR_TO_DATE('2011.03', '%Y.%m'))
ORDER BY monthcol DESC
```

The dates are now static (for testing), but i need to calculate the second value in the BETWEEN so that it will be exact -1 year to the first value of the BETWEEN section.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: okay, i found the solution for the syntax error: doesn't need the brackets on the BETWEEN values. But it still doesn't give me back any values...

Comment: Switch parameter dates. Between needs first expression to be less than second. And, if you stored dates as varchars you do not have to convert them back to date. Comparison will still work: `monthcol between '2011.03' and '2012.04')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the dates seem to be fixed length strings, why not use string comparison?:

```
SELECT DISTINCT monthcol
FROM bo_alerts
WHERE monthcol BETWEEN '2011.03' AND '2012.04'
ORDER BY monthcol DESC
```

Notice that I reversed the order of the dates to satisfy most SQL implementations having the first less than the second.

Comment: EPiC fail for me... and a facepalm too... Just needed to reverse the parameters, thank you very much! Do you have some solution for the 1 year calculation too? The first value comes outside, and for this i need to calculate -1 year. I assume: varchar->date->date-1year->varchar

Comment: Any schema which encodes dates using something other than a native database date or time type necessarily needs a lot of extra hassle to do arithmetic.  Perhaps alter the table structure so you can use the date arithmetic primitives directly.  This also improves maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Renove `'.'` from date it will work.

Try below query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT monthcol 
FROM bo_alerts 
WHERE concat(LEFT(monthcol,4),RIGHT(monthcol,2)) BETWEEN 201204  AND 201103
ORDER BY monthcol DESC
```