# Oracle Query with Date between - date column with varchar date

Tags: oracle, date

I just spent almost 2 days trying to figure out how I can make it but no success so far. So in details:

1. I have table where there is a column named DATE
2. Column DATE is VARCHAR and it contains date in following format: DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS PM/AM

I am tryning to create a oracle query to select records between dates but seems like becouse of VARCHAR DATE column format it's not so easy (or maybe even impossible).

Any chance to do something here ? Any trick ?

Thank you for any comments and help ( I am not an expert in case of database stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the model for the time portion is really `HH:MI:SS`, not `HH:MM:SS`. And, `DATE` is a terrible name for a column, since the same word is also a reserved keyword in Oracle.

Other than that: `to_date("DATE", 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')` converts the string to a value of **date** data type. This can, then, be used in a `between` comparison where the other terms are already in **date** data type.

Like this:

```
...
where to_date("DATE", 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') 
              between trunc(sysdate) - 1 and trunc(sysdate)
```

(meaning, things that happened "yesterday"). However, be careful with `between`, since that allows equality at both ends. In my example, things that happened at midnight THIS morning are still included in the output.

Comment: Hey, well yes it is. It's HH:MM:SS I tried solution from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206117/query-varchar-date-with-between but I am getting really wierd results here.

Comment: @Rafiq39 - do you understand what the problem is with MM there? MM means month, MI means minute. Did you mean to say yes, it's HH: **MI** :SS? And, your link is to a MySQL answer, while you tagged your question as Oracle. The MySQL code will not run in Oracle, it will throw an error, so what do you mean by "weird results"?

Comment: I ran it and I am getting : FORMAT CODE APPEARS TWICE

Comment: Ahhh sorry you're right. It's about naming. My fault so yes you are right it's MI like minutes.

Comment: I tried again. and I can only say it's working like a charm. So in this case if I want to use BETWEEN but with larger scope I have to pass here: trunc(sysdate) - 1 and trunc(sysdate) something more like dates right ?

Comment: @Rafiq39 - yes. There are different ways to do that (and, if your comparison "dates" are also strings in that format, you should use TO_DATE(...) on them as well).